# Range slider with value from symfony object

Tags: jquery, symfony

I have an object where are stored some coefficients.

I get my coefficients like this

Repository:

```
public function findVal()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
                  ->select('v.coef')
                  ->getQuery();

    $result = $query->getResult();


    //$ids = array_column($result, "coef");
    return $result;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function bienAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $devis = new Devis();

    $bien = new Bien();
    $formBien = $this->createForm(BienType::class, $bien);

    $valeur = $em->getRepository('ListeBundle:ValeurReconstruction')->findVal();

    //dump($valeur);

    //$jsonVal = json_encode($valeur);

    //dump(json_encode($valeur));

    $formBien->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formBien->isValid() && $formBien->isSubmitted()) {
      ...
    }

    return $this->render('DevisBundle:Devis:bien.html.twig', array(
        'formBien' => $formBien->createView(), 'valeur' => $valeur
    ));
}
```

Now i want to use those coef in my range slider so i need an js array for this.

```
$(function() {
var valMap = [0, 40.2, 50, 63, 90, 110, 125, 140, 160, 225, 250, ];
$("#slider-range").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(valMap[ui.value]);
    }
});
```

});

But I can't seem to find the right answer on the internet. And can i do this with symfony only by using the RangeType ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this could be to add a `<script>` inside your Twig template.

```
<script>
    window.valMap = [{{ valeur|join(',') }}];
</script>
```

Then use `window.valMap` inside your script.